# Albumart not working when audio file copied from one device to the other

Tags: android, mediastore, albumart

I  am able to add  a picture from gallery as album art for audio file using **MediaStore.Audio.Albums** .The path of the picture is saved in the Mediastore. It is working good within the device.  The album art is not working If the audio file is copied to other device or system. Please let me know how can I solve this.

Comment: The album art file is not connected to the mp3 file, so if you copy one of the two, the other one is not copied. Android works like this: IF in the folder where the mp3s related to an album lie there is a jpg file called `AlbumArt.jpg`, then it's used to show the picture. Otherwise, the media player will display the embedded mp3 file image (IF present).

Comment: @Rotwang If we downloaded any audio from internet  it will download only   audio file and albumart will not download . Albumart bind with audio file. I want do same thing.  what is the use of MediaMetadata in android.

Comment: As I told you, the AlbumArt.jpg file is a separate thing. I may or may not be present in an album folder. And only Android uses that system (I really don't know if iOS does the same). Some MediaPlayers do search for it on the web and download it. OR you can embed your album art in your mp3 files (each single one). But this would increase the mp3 file sizes.